# Pathfinding algorithm from A to A

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

I'm working on an application in which I can to generate a lap / circuit of a specific distance. The pathfinding algoritms I find (Dijkstra, A-star, etc) all seem to be designed to go from A to B in the lowest cost / most optimised way. I'm looking for suggestions how I can calculate a lap with the highest score (from A back to A)

Some more concrete specifics to understand the boundary conditions.
I want to generate laps shorter than say 10 km, in a city network.
In the most complex road networks, this means around 5.000 to 10.000 nodes or edges.
Each edge has a score from 0-10
Each edge has a distance in meters

I would like to find possible routes between 9 and 10 km, with the highest possible score.

So far, I have tried BFS and DFS, including some caching options in this, with not much luck. Beyond the 30th depth level it starts taking way too long. I have also tried to approach this as a linear programming problem but again there solving times are way too long (sometimes over an hour).

I am looking for suggestions / examples in which other ways I can approach this problem. Since Dijkstra like algorithms are very fast, this seems a feasible problem to solve in say under ten seconds, but given my current results I'm also eager to know if you think this is a realistic expectation.

Comment: Since you are looking for a path with highest score, it is like looking for the longest path, which is NP-Hard (while the shortest path is not). So the problem is computationally intractable by nature. Is your graph acyclic by any chance ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's a graph of road networks in a city, so unfortunately not.